# Regex: How to replace the matched text with a HTML element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a description from database coming like this :

```
"And here is the {{dog}} which is chasing the {{cat}}"
```

And instead of having `{{dog}}` I want to replace it by `<span class="dog"/>`

I tried this : [My Attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/2v1ys7cz/1/)

I know how I can exctract but I don't know how to replace these parts only and then do my display.

Thanks you!

EDIT :

```
var input = "And here is the {{dog}} which is chasing the {{cat}}";
var regex = /{{(.*?)}}/g;

var matches, output = [];
while (matches = regex.exec(input)) {
    output.push(matches[1]);

}
```

I want my final string to be : 
`And here is the <span class="dog"/> which is chasing the <span class='cat'/>`

Comment: This is displaying an image! Sorry for syntax, I'm using React that's why I wrote `<span class="dog"/>`. I just chose span but it would be an image or whatever.

Comment: *"I tried this : My Attempt"* The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a capturing group like this:

`$1` indicates the text matched within the parentheses (capturing group) and can be used in `replace` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Using_a_regular_expression_to_change_data_format))

```js
const str = "And here is the {{dog}} which is chasing the {{cat}}"
const newStr = str.replace(/{{(\w+)}}/g, "<span class='$1' />")

console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to replace and capture the text you wish.

```js
const data = "And here is the {{dog}} which is chasing the {{cat}}";

const res = data.replace(/\{{2}([a-z]+)\}{2}/g, '<span class="$1">$1</span>');

document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

```css
span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```